# How to send text by HttpPost method?

Tags: java, text, connection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have no idea, how to send some text using HTTPCLIENT (java // apache) library. I need to send parameters by text to server. 
Any idea?

Comment: Did you try searching it? Its very trivial and basic stuff.

Comment: I just, check how some website is sending data to server, in Fiddler web debugger, and i must implement same way to send this data, but from java application, by httpclient. It's sending this data by text - it was in textview in Fiddler, not by xml, or json. And i don't know, how to send the text. Perhaps it is simple, but, I've got only 2 days experience with httpclient. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What type of data you want to send to server ?

Comment: Ok, I found solution - StringEntity (in httpclient 4 api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have `some-remote-server` as your remote server address and `some-servlet` as your remote servlet which accepts `param1`, `param2` etc.. with its respective values on request. If the remote servlet accept GET call you can use below to send the request;

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(); //You could use PostMethod if servlet accept POST

  String request ="http://some-remote-server/some-servlet?param1=value1&param2=value2";
  httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
  getMethod.setURI(new URI(request, false, null));
  ...
```

And then recieve the response return from the remote servlet like this;

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream());
ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the tool, try [RestClient Tool](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rest-client) for eclipse.
It has great support for testing restful web-services. It has option to specify,

1. Header Parameter,
2. Query Parameter,
3. Body Text
4. Request type (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS,TRACE)

Comment: OP is not asking for web services.